# Mean difference between pairs of valid cases

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working on data structured like this:

```
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(
  id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
  var1 = c(2, NA, 3, 1, 2),
  var2 = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 2),
  var3 = c(5, 8, 6, NA, NA),
  var4 = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55)
)
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  eid    var1  var2  var3  var4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1         2     1     5    11
2 2        NA     2     8    22
3 3         3    NA     6    33
4 4         1    NA    NA    44
5 5         2     2    NA    55
```

I need to compute the unstandardised mean difference between each pair of valid cases across `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, for each row taken singularly.

I would like to get a resulting variable in the tibble with the mean difference between any two variables (out of the 3 I listed before).

If I were to do it by hand for the first row, I would calculate the differences first

> 2 - 1 = 1

> 1 - 5 = -4

> 2 - 5 = -3

then take the module, as I am interested in the distances only

> |1| = 1

> |-4| = 4

> |-3| = 3

and then compute an average of the differences

> 1+4+3 / 3 = 2.67

An important exception would be that, if an NA or more is present, it shouldn't be considered in the count, neither in the difference nor in the average. E.g. in the 2nd row, I'd need the result to be 6, not NA.

The expected scenario with 2 NAs would be the average difference to be 0, but NA would be acceptable.

What I tried so far didn't work, as it does not sum by row:

```
df %>%
  mutate(meandiff = sum(
    abs(sum(var1, -var2, na.rm = TRUE)),
    abs(sum(var2, -var3, na.rm = TRUE)),
    abs(sum(var1, -var3, na.rm = TRUE)),
    na.rm = TRUE
    ) / 3)
```

I was thinking of using the function `rowsum()`, but I need the pairwise difference and not for all three variables at the same.

Would you be able to help me find out a way to compute it in R?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the expected values?

Comment: I would like to get a vector with the mean difference between any two variables (out of the 3 I listed before). Doing it by hand for the first row, I would calculate the differences first (2-1 = 1; 1-5 = -4; 2-5 = -3), taking the module as I am interested in the distances only (i.e., 1, 4, 3), and then compute an average of the differences (1+4+3/3 =2.67).

Comment: You did not divide by two in that comment, but adding that back in, the answers below agree with `1.333` for the first row. (BTW: my request for expected values was meant to be answered in the question itself, since comments can be skipped by readers or hidden by the Stack interface. I suggest you [edit] your question and put it in there. Thanks!)

Comment: An important exception would be that, if an NA or more is present, it should not be considered neither in the difference nor in the average (...reason why what I tried was absolutely ridicolous, now that I think of it).

The expected scenario with 2 NAs would be the average difference to be 0.

Comment: ... which is even *more* reason you need to add expected results for all rows in your answer. (*And you need to add that not-so-trivial caveat to the question itself.*) That's useful, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, absolutely, I updated the question with what I added here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
func <- function(...) {
  dots <- na.omit(c(...))
  sum(abs(diff(c(dots, dots[1]))), na.rm = TRUE) / length(dots)
}
df %>%
  mutate(meandiff = mapply(func, var1, var2, var3))
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   id     var1  var2  var3  var4 meandiff
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 1         2     1     5    11     2.67
# 2 2        NA     2     8    22     6   
# 3 3         3    NA     6    33     3   
# 4 4         1    NA    NA    44     0   
# 5 5         2     2    NA    55     0
```

(This calculates `var3 - var1` for the third mid-`sum` value instead of your `var1 - var3`, but since you use `abs` it should not matter.)

Comment: See my edit, now the first matches your expected output.

Comment: That works, thank you so much! Do you mind if I ask if you can explain why you used `unlist(list())` in your solution?

Comment: `(...)` allows variadic arguments: I did not know if you needed to hard-code exactly three, so instead I used `function(...)` which allows any number of arguments. Inside the function, one can use `list(...)` or `c(...)` depending on what you need of the objects (realizing that mixed-`class` really requires `list(...)`); after that, `diff` needs a vector (not a list), so `unlist(.)` around it. I've been doing so much work with mixed-class anon-funcs like this that I defaulted to `unlist(list(...))`; you can use `dots <- c(...)` instead and it should work just fine. (I'll edit in a sec ...)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    meandiff = rowSums(
    cbind(
      abs(var1-var2) / 2,
      abs(var2-var3) / 2,
      abs(var1-var3) / 2
    ), na.rm = TRUE) / 3
  )
```

Btw, if you want to remove the `NA` and calculate the mean, will `/ 3` still be proper?

Comment: I updated the question, see if it makes more sense now